# XML error when trying to get all knowledge base articles (Kayako .NET API)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement Kayako knowledge base on my Customer portal using the .NET API with Asp.net MVC framework, and I'm trying to get all articles, which looks like this in my backend-class:

```
var articles = client.Knowledgebase.GetKnowledgebaseArticles();
```

When I do this, I get an error that says: "There is an error in the XML-Document (line, column)".
This is actually all I'm doing atm. Getting Tickets, Users and Departments all work like a charm, so I know Kayako client is setup correctly. I also get an inner exception that says:

*"When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object."*

And another Inner Exception that says:

*"Make sure your method arguments are in the right format."*
Has anyone seen this error?

I've looked up the XML-document error and that seems to have something to do with Culture during the parsing of dates.
I live in Sweden, but I don't know how I would handle this since I don't manually parse anything. The method is from Kayako API so I have no access to the actual code. I just want to save the articles to a KnowledgebaseArticleCollection which is a List of KnowledgebaseArticle.
I can't find anything about the inner exception about the DateTime parsing though.
Grabbing one article with:

```
client.Knowledgebase.GetKnowledgebaseArticle()
```

works as it should.

Here's the full Exception:

> > System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Det finns ett fel i XML-dokumentet
> >     (1411, 2).   Source=System.Xml   StackTrace:
> >            vid System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> >     xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> >            vid System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader
> >     textReader)
> >            vid KayakoRestApi.Net.KayakoApiRequest.ProcessWebRequest[TTarget](WebRequest
> >     request)
> >            vid KayakoRestApi.Net.KayakoApiRequest.ExecuteCall[TTarget](String
> >     apiMethod, String parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod)
> >            vid KayakoRestApi.Net.KayakoApiRequest.ExecuteGet[TTarget](String
> >     apiMethod)
> >            vid KayakoRestApi.Controllers.KnowledgebaseController.GetKnowledgebaseArticles()
> >            vid Domain.Concrete.Kayako.GetCategoryArticles(Int32 id) i c:\Martin\Konica
> >     Minolta\KM-NET\MainProject\Domain\Concrete\Kayako.cs:rad 315
> >            vid WebUI.Controllers.HomeController.Index() i c:\Martin\Konica Minolta\KM-NET\MainProject\WebUI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:rad 21
> >            vid lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
> >     controller, Object[] parameters)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
> >     parameters)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
> >     asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> >     asyncResult)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
> >     asyncResult, Object tag)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
> >     asyncResult)
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
> >            vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
> >     InnerException: System.FormatException
> >            HResult=-2146233033
> >            Message=Indatasträngen hade ett felaktigt format.
> >            Source=mscorlib
> >            StackTrace:
> >                 vid System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
> >     parseDecimal)
> >                 vid System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
> >                 vid System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
> >                 vid Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderKnowledgebaseArticleCollection.Read4_KnowledgebaseArticle(Boolean
> >     isNullable, Boolean checkType)
> >                 vid Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderKnowledgebaseArticleCollection.Read5_kbarticles()
> >     InnerException:

I'm sorry if this information isn't enough, let me know if you need anything else to be able to solve this issue. I'm quite new to programming.

Thanks in advance!

Martin Johansson

Comment: Please provide the full exception, rather than just the message. Currently we've no idea where it's coming from. And you say you've got two different exceptions - in the same stack trace, or for two different operations?

Comment: Ok I pasted the exception from Visual Studio. Some of it is translated into Swedish I'm afraid. As for the two Inner exceptions, both of them come from the same line of code and they are written in the Troubleshooting tips in VS. But when I look at details, there is a completely different inner exception. Not quite sure why

Comment: Well it sounds like the XML document is broken, basically. Without knowing anything about Kayako, I don't know what XML document is being loaded at all... do you?

Comment: I don't. I have an example response on their API documentation (https://kayako.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DEV/REST+-+KnowledgebaseArticle), but the .NET api is built by the community so the company doesn't give any support for it. I was actually hoping it had something to do with the culture when it comes to , and . in decimals or something like that.

Comment: Hmm. I would have added the `kayako` tag, but it doesn't look like it exists. If there's a decent community forum for it, I'd ask there. It sounds like it may well be a bug in the client library.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I've created an account on their community forum but for some reason I'm not allowed to post questions there. That's why I tried here.